# Python MongoDB aggregation delete doc by _id

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Well I'm Working with python and MongoDB but I got many problems with aggregation.

My principal collection have this structure

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bef5692d0c24110b0004671"
},
"dateAdded": {
    "$date": "2018-10-16T23:45:22.974Z"
},
"phoneNumber": "xxxxxxxx",
"phoneType": "pay",
"duration": 0,
"apiCallsCount": 3,
"tenant": {
    "$oid": "5b3fd3f99a8f4e04900c4e17"
},
"sessionStatus": "EXPIRED"
```

}

My second collection have this structure

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bf46869d0c2410decc4e050"
    },
    "dateAdded": {
        "$date": "2018-11-20T20:02:49.281Z"
    },
    "resolutionStatus": "Complete",
    "finalResult": "OK",
    "intention": "Query_one",
    "call": {
        "$oid": "5bef5692d0c24110b0004671"
    },
    "duration": 0,
    "dateExpired": {
        "$date": "2018-11-20T20:04:01.732Z"
    },
    "queryType": "phone",
    "tenant": {
        "$oid": "5b3fd3f99a8f4e04900c4e17"
    }
}
```

First I need to get all the docs from the first collection before a specific date, next with all of this docs using the _id I need to get all the docs in second collection (the _id in the first collection is the same that call in the second collection) and delete it from the collection.

I think that I need a lookup and my aggregation looks like this but isn't working. I don't have a clue that what is suposed I need for this problem.

```
self.db.get_collection(first_collection).aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
              from: second_collection,
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "call",
              as: "inventory_docs"
          }
   }
])
```

Comment: So you wanted to delete entire doc in `second_collection` or just call field ? What is your DB version ?

Comment: I want to delete all the doc from the collection, MongoDB 4.2.6 Community

Comment: So you wanted to delete all docs in `second_collection` which have reference in `first_collection` after filter `first_collection` on dateAdded ?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation is heavily used for reads but not much on writes. So there are only two stages in aggregation [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) and [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) that are capable of writing data to database - which are not useful in your case, though they're it might not be feasible than doing this with normal [.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) & [.deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/index.html).

You can do it in two steps, try below basic code :

1) First get `_id`'s of all docs from `first_collection` that are to be deleted from `second_collection`.

```
ids = list(self.db.get_collection(first_collection).find({dateAdded : {$lte : inputDate }},{ _id :1 })) // Use `$lte` or `$lt`.
```

2) Delete all docs from `second_collection` where `call` field's value exists in any of the `ids` returned in above step :

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

if ids:  /** Checking to only execute this deletion operation when ids is not empty */
   convertedIds = [] // From Step 1, `ids` is an arrays of strings, We need to convert back to type `ObjectId()`'s to match with `call` field in DB.
   for id in ids:
       convertedIds.append(ObjectId(id))
   deletedDocs = self.db.get_collection(second_collection).delete_many({ call : {$in : convertedIds }});
   print(deletedDocs.deleted_count) // Just give no.of docs deleted
```

Just in case if you wanted to return the docs that got deleted, try [.findAndModify()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/index.html) instead of `.deleteMany()`. I think pymongo's equivalent of `.findAndModify()` which is [.find_and_modify()](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find_and_modify#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify) got deprecated & you might need to use `.find_one_delete()` but in order to use it you can't pass-in an array to `call` field in filter like above : `{ call : {$in : convertedIds }}`. So you need to iterate on `ids` & do `{ call : id }` - but this makes multiple delete DB calls - I prefer not to do it & will stick with `.delete_many()` unless I really need deleted docs information to be returned.

**Ref :** [.delete_many()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=delete_many#pymongo.collection.Collection.delete_many), [.find_one_and_delete()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find_and_modify#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_delete) & [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html)

Comment: I do the step one, no problem, in the step two I have the convertedIds with a structure like this:

```
[ObjectId('5c784a3ed0c24127589237e9'), ObjectId('5c784e7dd0c24127589237f9'), ObjectId('5c784e97d0c2412758923802'),...]
```
But I got problem with the delete_many, my error is this:

File "C:\Users\madeleon\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 203, in _raise_last_write_error
    raise WriteError(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error)
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Missing expected field "locale"

Comment: I just change to this deletedDocs = self.db.get_collection(second_collection).delete_many({ call : {$in : convertedIds }}) an is working perfectly thanks! the program is pretty fast deleting more than 150,000 docs in just 35 seconds, before I'm doing using a for loop and it takes more than 20 minutes

Comment: @maxdlr.7 : My bad I've forget to remove `.toArray()` which is for node.js & projection `{_id :1}` which for `.find()`, fixed it in my answer :-)